# use fragments with vanilla apollo client

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo, apollo-client

So I stumbed on this doc on their site [enter link description here](http://dev.apollodata.com/core/fragments.html) which looks great but then when I did this locally I get an error message their is no export createFragment in apollo-client. I found some discussion of the docs error [enter link description here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1193#issuecomment-276542509) which leads me to look in graphql-tag but I can't find anything there. Can anyone point me in the right direction to using fragments in Vanilla apollo client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that `createFragment` hab been removed from the API.

If you want to create a fragment you can use `gql` from the `graphql-tag` package (included in `react-apollo`).

So it could look like this:

```js
const CommentsFragment = gql `
fragment CommentsFragment on Comment {
  id
  createdAt
  content
}`;

const CommentsQuery = gql `
query Comments {
  ...CommentsFragment
}
${CommentsFragment}
`;
```

Comment: for what its worth you can use graphql-tag outside of react apollo as standalone project. I ended up using `.graphql` files with graphql-tag/loader in webpack so I could avoid the gql template string. For whatever reason I had issues with just using gql and fragments.  I liked the `.graphql` files because the syntax is very clean and similar to what you would do in graphiql.